# Мороз по коже что делает?

Tags: фразеология

Холодно, мороз по коже...  А дальше как, какие варианты? И вообще, пользуетесь вы таким выражением или оно уже устарело? Может быть, есть современная фразеология на эту тему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

п(р)одирает, пробирает (в прямом смысле)

прошёл, пробегает всякий раз, как... (в переносном смысле, о кратковременном ощущении)

В переносном смысле глагол чаще всего опускается. Не помню, чтобы мне приходилось применять это выражение (обычно так описывают кому-то свою фатальную забывчивость, реже - холодную погоду), но воспринимаю его как вполне естественное.

Comment: Тут не только забывчивость, всякое может случиться, и ощущения разне, от ужаса до восторга. Да, вы правы, глагол чаще опускается, но вот грамматики утверждают, что мороз не должен "продирать кожу насквозь"

Comment: Вера, если ошибка в глаголе, тогда это ошибка стилистическая, а не грамматическая.

Comment: Кстати, глагол продрать зафиксирован словарем со словом мороз.

Comment: Где зафиксирован и в каком выражении? Есть такое сочетание:  мороз до костей пробирает/продирает, тогда правильно.

Comment: Дрожь (мороз) продрал. Разг. Об ощущении, испытываемом при сильном ознобе, страхе.  См. Словарь Кузнецова.

Answer (score 2):

...подирает, дерет, продирает,пробирает, пробегает. Лично я пользуюсь редко.   А в своем окружении услышать не могу  - большая часть армяноязычные. В национальном корпусе не искали?

Comment: Вот нашла: "Мороз по коже пробирает, как вспомню, что бы могло выйти, если б я послал (Ф. М. Достоевский).  Только, оказывается,  классик допустил грамматическую ошибку, догадайтесь какую.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду двойное использование наклонения: что бы... если б. Да?

Comment: Нет, ошибка в первом предложении.

Answer (score 2):

Так говорили классики:

Я тебе продам такую пару, просто мороз по коже подирает! (Н. В. Гоголь). Отчего у меня ― просто мороз по коже подирает, как только я подумаю, что мне надо, наконец, к ним съездить? (И. C. Тургенев). Ух, батюшки, и теперь мороз по коже подирает, а тогда! (М. Н. Загоскин).

Так говорят современники:

У меня мороз по коже продирает, когда я слышу  о тех, кто ей верен. А кроме чертей были другие картины, такие, от которых мороз по коже пробирал. Однако вместо привычного жужжания раздался свербящий скрежет, от которого пробирал мороз по коже.

Грамматики возмущаются заменой приставки: **по коже, а не сквозь кожу**, но кто их слушает!

И вот интересно, кто прав? В конце концов, некоторые фразеологизмы надо вообще расшифровывать, а тут какая-то приставка, смысл и так понятен. И отступает, отступает "культура русской речи" по всем позициям. Но может быть, это естественный процесс развития языка?

Comment: Вера, если честно, то я не понял: если ошибка в приставке, т.е. надо говорить: по коже, а не сквозь кожу, так где ошибка у Достоевского?

Comment: Просто приставка ПРО имеет значение "сквозь, через", а приставка ПО имеет значение "вдоль поверхности". Получается: мороз подирает по коже (это мурашки) или  продирает до костей (сквозь тело). Кстати,  в последнем случае так говорят только о холодной погоде.

Comment: А-а,понятно. Вера, см. мой комментарий про глагол продирает.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Я хотел ответить что "продирает". Но я не вижу причин для возмущения "грамматиков" (грамматистов, наверно, да?). Во-первых, "про" тут вполне уместна. Почему бы и не **через** кожу? А во-вторых, приставка "про" не обязательно имеет значение "насквозь". "Проживает", "проводит", "пробегает" - три разных значения, но все не "насквозь".

Comment: Вопрос из книги "Культура русской речи" (1995 год). Там говорится, что продирать - это прорывать насквозь, разрывать. Мороз по коже - это пробегание мурашек, поверхностное воздействие. (Можно еще сказать: мороз пробегает). В обиходной речи устарелый глагол "подирать" заменен более понятным и экспрессивным "продирать". В литературном языке употребление фразеологизма в искаженном виде не рекомендуется (информация из книги).

Comment: Но там вряд ли говориться, что это единственное значение "про". А если и говорится такое, то выкиньте эту книжицу. Я вам три контрпримера привел. Если предметно по поводу подобных книг и самого предмета "культура речи". Это, имхо, в современном состоянии голый субъективизм. Я у такого уважаемого автора как Марина Королева едва ли в каждом "уроке" могу найти если не ошибку, то противоречие непоясненное. Так что авторитарные суждения тут не прокатывают. А кто, кстати, автор этого Вашего филиокве?

Comment: Некий Скворцов Л.И. доктор филологических наук, профессор, зав. кафедрой стилистики  русского языка, проректор Литературного института имени А.М. Горького.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2_%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87 - Этот? да уж, почетный "грамматик".

Comment: Считаете, что не заслуживает доверия? А сколько книг написал!Например: Культура русской речи: словарь-справочник. — М.: Академия, 2003.

Comment: Я в своем ответе объяснился. Число книг мне не шибко важно, "советская культура" - это оксюморон.

Answer (score 2):

Ну коли пошла такая пьянка... Еще о классиках.

Мороз продирает по коже при воспоминании битком набитого зала в 3000 человек, куда я попал в первый день приезда в Берлин и где встретился с «близкими» некогда мне, и с рядом старых знакомств, и с «дорнахцами» , и со Штейнером.

[Андрей Белый, (1928)]

Но и меня иногда мороз продирает по коже, когда я думаю об этих фактах. [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Пикник на обочине (1971)]

Тут такая штука. Никто не возражает, что исторически было "подирает". Но мне не понравился разговор про неназванных "грамматиках", которые типа, возражают против замены на "продирают", на том и том только основании, что "про" - это насквозь. Не говоря уж о том, что семантика обеих приставок могла порядком измениться, слово "подирает" вообще не всеми словарями фиксируется как современное.

================
(+)
Vera, вот теперь я благодаря @Шкерцов'у могу точно сказать, что "подирает" - форма верная.

Но гр. Скворцов все равно сказал глупость. "Подирает" - это частичное, неполное действие к "дерет". Как "побаивается", "погуливает", "позевывает" - и проч. К поверхностному действию не имеет отношения.

Другими словами, настоящий мороз дерет, а морозец - подирает. Вот откуда эта приставка. Так что сильный мороз вполне может и продирать.

Comment: Но это же устойчивое выражение, поэтому туда может входить устаревшее слово. Если же рассматривать сочетание "продирать по коже" (без мороза), то оно некорректно, тогда  правильно "продирать кожу".

Comment: Это другой аргумент. Я говорил о "грамматиках", которые-де апеллируют к значению приставки. Если вы аргументируете устойчивостью выражения, то это уже исключает разговоры про изменение значения отельных морфов при из замене.

Comment: Хотя я реально сомневаюсь и в том, насколько выражение устойчиво. "Мороз по коже" - да. А вот глагол при этом довольно подвижен.

Comment: И каков вывод? Мороз продирает по коже - это корректно? Можно так говорить?

Comment: Выводы делайте сами. Я себе такой задачи не ставил. Все что сказал - самодостаточно. . Я думаю, что вполне корректно, но не настаиваю.

Answer (score 2):

Мороз **дерет**.

а что тут еще надо писать?

Comment: А ведь верно. И отсюда верная форма "подирает" - как частичное действие.

Comment: Ну да, колет - покалывает, дерет - подирает. У Скворцова форма "дерет" тоже упоминается.